# Controller Returning Incorrect DateTime Format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, datetime, grid, telerik

When using the the Telerik DataSourceRequest within my controller any property with a DateTime data type is being returned as

```
{"Data":[{"EffectiveStart":"\/Date(1393660800000)\/"}
```

Instead of `MM/dd/yy`

The property on my Model is:

```
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime EffectiveStart;
```

I have also included the js culture reference for Telerik in my file and initiated `kendo.culture()` with no luck.  What am I missing?

As requested here is the controller:

```
    public ActionResult Grid_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, int id)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new MyEntities())
            {

                var query = from refA in db.Entity
                            join refB in db.Entity on refA.ID equals refB.ID
                            where refA.ID == id
                            select new ResultList
                            {
                                ResultId = refA.PayeeId,
                                EffectiveStart = refA.EffectiveStart,
                            };

                List<ResultList> myvar = query.ToList();

                DataSourceResult result = myvar.ToDataSourceResult(request);

                return Json(result);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can we see the code of the controller? The whole method

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could do is replace

```
return Json(result);
```

by

```
return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
```

BTW, you will need Newtonsoft.Json to use JsonConvert.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the responses.  The resolution on this was to include some client side JavaScript which formats the field at runtime:

```
function toDate(value)
    var dateRegExp = /^\/Date\((.*?)\)\/$/;
    var date = dateRegExp.exec(value);
    return new Date(parseInt(date[1]));
}
```

Then add a to the Telerik Grid column:

```
.ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString( toDate(DateCreated), \"MM/dd/yyyy\" ) #")
```